# C# Column Chart skips XValueMember value but displays YValueMember value

Tags: c#, visual-studio, charts, column-chart, dotnetcharting

> Code

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("select top 10 p.customername, ISNULL(SUM(c.total),0) as total from table_customerpurchases as c Left join table_customers as p on p.customerid = c.cid where cid!='Default' and cid!='c10022' group by customername order by total desc", con);
        adapt.Fill(ds);
        chart1.DataSource = ds;
       
        chart1.Series["Customers"].XValueMember = "customername";
        chart1.Series["Customers"].XValueType = ChartValueType.String;
        
        chart1.Series["Customers"].YValueMembers = "total";
        chart1.Series["Customers"].YValueType = ChartValueType.Double;
        chart1.Titles.Add("Customers Purchases Chart");
        chart1.Series["Customers"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
        con.Close();
```

> Output Result Picture of Column Chart
> [image: Picture of Column Chart]

> As you can see when i put break there and see in dataset visualizer; All data is filled in there
> [image: Dataset Values Picture]

**> Problem Description**

I don't know where the problem is that it is showing column bar but skips 'XValueMember' value.
Also why it is not creating separate column line for every 'XValueMember'.

Comment: It skips values because there is not enough room to display them. You could tweak the display be changing the font or tilting the labels or add a 2nd line and maybe some other ways.. Or you make the label texts shorter.

Comment: Have you tried TaW’s suggestion? Does it work?

Comment: I have made an answer. If you accept it, you could click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Comment: I solved it by some other way by setting AxisX.Maximum = 10 and AxisX.Interval = 1.
It also worked fine but now that i saw your @JialeXue-MSFT answer i changed mine.
Because mine was just work things out somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

您只需要在代码中添加以下三行代码即可：

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1; //Set the X axis coordinate interval to 1
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffset = 1; //Set the X axis coordinate offset to 1
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.IsStaggered = true; //Set whether to display staggered, for example, the time with a lot of data is divided into two rows to display
```

Output:

[image]

Or like this:

```
//chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.IsStaggered = true;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle=90//Rotate 90 degrees;
```

Output:
[image]